# Struts2 different authentication for sub-set of the application

Tags: authentication, jakarta-ee, struts2

We are developing an application in Java with struts2. We have a default authentication mechanism (LDAP) for the web application. 
We would like to enable a different authentication for a subset of the web app for some external users (Not on LDAP but from database table login/password) who have limited access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can achieve this by some sort of custom [Interceptor](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/interceptors.html).You need to identity which part of the application you want that authentication and can place your custom interceptor based on your requirement.